# how can i add an offset to an existing bone?

Tags: rigging

Beginner rigger here (sorry for stupid question):

I have an armature with a bone.

If i parent the mesh to the bone, it moves perfectly with it.

How can i change the offset of that relationship afterwards?

Or is the only way to go, unparent the mesh, move the bone and parent again?

Comment: the parenting is based on the vertex groups, so as long as you don't edit the mess in a way that modifies vertex group membership, you should be able to simply move vertices around in edit mode, if I understand your question.

Comment: that simple, damn ;) yes, you understood it right. thanks. If you wanna write an answer...i will check that

Comment: Done.  It wasn't a stupid question by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parenting is based on the vertex groups, so as long as you don't edit the mesh in a way that modifies vertex group membership, you should be able to simply move vertices around in edit mode.

If you do need to modify vertex group membership and only make a few changes, you can manage this just by adding and removing vertices from groups, possibly changing their weights.

You might have to do a little weight painting if there are other bones that influence the part of the mesh you edit.

Comment: thank you for that fast help!

Comment: You're welcome.  Thanks for the upvote as well as the accept.